# Algorithm issues with newer version of [ms-identity-java-webapp] token?

Tags: java, azure, azure-active-directory

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-java-webapp/tree/master/msal-java-webapp-sample

when I am using the latest (latest version)downloaded application [ms-identity-java-webapp], it gives me a token that is not getting parsed it gives below exception
"com.nimbusds.jose.JOSEException: Unsupported JWS algorithm RS256, must be HS256, HS384 or HS512".

But when I am using the old downloaded project [ms-identity-java-webapp] ( which was downloaded by me in sept 2021), the token by this project is getting parsed. Why the token doesn't work for the newer version of the app?

ms-identity-java-webapp not parsing the token

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

***The error you are getting could be due to version compatibility issues.***

I cloned [GitHub project](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-java-webapp/tree/master/msal-java-webapp-sample) to my environment to run and check if it works, I didn't face any such issues.

**Steps followed:**

- Registered a new application in Azure Active Directory.
- Replaced the `client_id, client_secret and Tenant_id` values in the `application.properties` code with the values of the newly created application.

**application.properties:**

```
#AAD configuration
aad.clientId=097dXX-XXX-XXXX-XXXX-556XXXXX
aad.authority=https://login.microsoftonline.com/<Tenant_ID/
aad.secretKey=<Client_secret_value>
aad.redirectUriSignin=https://jwt.ms
aad.redirectUriGraph=https://localhost:8443/msal4jsample/graph/me
aad.msGraphEndpointHost=https://graph.microsoft.com/
```

Registered the ***redirectURI*** in `Registered application in Azure Active directory=>Authentication`:

[image]

Open ***Terminal***, navigate to the *root directory* of the *application* and run the command `mvn clean install` :

[image]

[image]

Run `mvn spring-boot:run`:

[image]

[image]

**Response:**

[image]

[image]

***Code got generated as shown below:***

[image]